# Understanding Google Cloud Platform's Autoscaler

Tags: google-compute-engine

Autoscaler is recently added as an option to Google Cloud Platform. If I understand it correctly, you can create a template VM and Autoscaler will increase the number of VMs, if necessary, based on this template VM.

My main question is: this template VM doesn't contain the default files in `/var/www`. Even when I create a snapshot and use the snapshot for the template, the folder `/var/www` is empty. So how can I use autoscale and sync all VMs (auto)created. I already use a Cloud SQL and are moving images to a bucket. But I guess nobody's website or app will work with empty / newly-installed VMs.

Comment: Shot in the dark here, but are you starting from an app that you had copied to var/www or are you by any chance using a click to deploy application? The reason I ask is because for many of the click to deploy apps, a separate data disk is used and var/www links to this disk.  This might explain why snapshotting the boot disk does not copy the application files.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Yes, I used click to deploy features. That might explain a lot. The current behavior is really strange. Detaching and attaching a hard disk results in losing all data. Another strange thing... When I create a snapshot and create a disk out of it and attach it to a new VM, even the apache modules I enabled on the source, aren't enabled in the snapshot/disk.

Answer (score 1):

- Please edit this out to be a comment, do not have enough points to comment.

You actually can attach additional disks, they just have to be in read-only mode. As stated here [1](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instance-templates/create) (look for `--disk PROPERTY=VALUE`)

Answer (score 0):

Instance Templates (the foundational component that scales up new virtual machines with Autoscaler) at this time doesn't support creating and attaching separate non-boot data disks.

So if you wanted to transfer an existing deployment that uses multiple disks to use Autoscaler, you should first copy the contents of the data disk to the boot disk.

This is the case with many of the [Click to Deploy solutions](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/lamp/click-to-deploy) which place the contents of /var/www on a separate disk.

Comment: Hi Chris, I did some tests. If I detach the additional disk (only boot disk left) and I change /var/www/index.html. That changed file is on a new instance with a snapshot as source from the boot disk.

But when I do the same at instances with an additional disk, then the files within var/www aren't moved / installed. The folder is just empty.

Comment: I'm not following you, can you explain again or email me at my <first initial>+<last name>@google.com and we can chat more?